# draw graph with n node in matlab

Tags: matlab, math

I have a vector with x and y position.
If `n=3` I have array with length 6. Each cell value is a position on space

```
A= [x1 y1 ,x2 y2 ,x3 y3]
// As example A = [2 3.122 , 1.3 6, 2.1 5.6]
```

how can I a complete graph of this positions ?

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gplot(A,Coordinates)` plots a graph of the nodes defined in Coordinates according to the n-by-n adjacency matrix A, where n is the number of nodes. Coordinates is an n-by-2 matrix, where n is the number of nodes and each coordinate pair represents one node

For two-dimensional data, Coordinates(i,:) = [x(i) y(i)] denotes node i, and Coordinates(j,:) = [x(j)y(j)] denotes node j. If node i and node j are connected, A(i,j) or A(j,i) is nonzero; otherwise, A(i,j) and A(j,i) are zero.

```
doc gplot
```

for more info.

For your example, with the trivial all ones adjacency matrix, you'll get:

```
A = [2 3.122 , 1.3 6, 2.1 5.6]; % #  where A= [x1 y1 ,x2 y2 ,x3 y3]
gplot(ones(3),[A(1:2:end)',A(2:2:end)'],'-*')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `X` vector and a `Y` vector like this:

```
X = A(:,1);
Y = A(:,2);
```

and then simply use plot:

```
plot(X, Y);
```